# Update JS object based on local storeage

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I'm trying to create a setup object with all app URL's in it but some of the URL values are dynamic and stored in the local storage. My question is how do I update a setup object based on latest local storage?

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:slideonlyone('addon1')">Addon 1</a>
<a href="javascript:slideonlyone('addon2')">Addon 2</a>
<a href="javascript:slideonlyone('addon3')">Addon 3</a>
```

Javascript:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('TmpAdd','default');

var AppUrl = {
    'jsonUrl1' : 'http://myurl.com/' + window.localStorage.getItem('TmpAdd'),
    'jsonUrl2' : 'http://myurl.com/category/' + window.localStorage.getItem('TmpAdd')
};

function slideonlyone(item) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('TmpAdd', item );
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('TmpAdd'),AppUrl.jsonUrl1);      
}
```

See working example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BebvE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the URLs whenever you change the local storage values:

```
var AppUrl = { };
updateURLs('default');

function updateURLs(tmpAdd) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('TmpAdd', tmpAdd);
    AppUrl.jsonUrl1 = 'http://myurl.com/' + tmpAdd;
    AppUrl.jsonUrl1 = 'http://myurl.com/category/' + tmpAdd;
}

function slideonlyone(item) {
    updateURLs(item);
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('TmpAdd'));
    console.log(AppUrl.jsonUrl1);
}
```

Another way would be to turn `jsonUrl1` and `jsonUrl2` into functions that look at the current value of `localStorage.TmpAdd` and create a URL appropriately. You could make the functions look like ordinary properties by using [custom property getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)<sup>MDN</sup>, but this is probably an overkill.

```
var AppUrl = {

    'jsonUrl1' : function() {
        return 'http://myurl.com/' +
            window.localStorage.getItem('TmpAdd');
    },

    'jsonUrl2' : function() {
        return 'http://myurl.com/category/' +
            window.localStorage.getItem('TmpAdd');
    }
};

// usage: replace AppUrl.jsonUrl1 with AppUrl.jsonUrl1()
```

Comment: So the only way is to create a function and call it all the time if I need to refresh the object... a bit messy

Comment: if I do this way I could use a function as object property AppUrl.jsonUrl1 = dybamicObject();

Comment: Quite the contrary. Encapsulating the logic of updating the local storage and the URLs in a function is clean and removes the messy `window.localStorage.setItem('TmpAdd', item );` from your main code. But you don't have to do that -- see the second half of my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tom the second one is quite good I might do some tweaks to it ;-)